# Use date calculations in Linux bash curl to get day of week

Tags: linux, bash

I have a cronjob that uses curl to send http post to my home-assistant.io server that in turn uses google_say to make my Google Home tell people to start getting ready in the morning... for a bit of fun. :)

It works great but when trying to add some dynamic content such as saying the day of the week, I'm struggling with the construct of using date within curl.  I would also like it determine the number of days until the weekend.  I have tried the following:

```
"message": "Its "'"$(date +%A)"'" morning and x days until the weekend.  Time to get ready."
```

but get an error saying:

```
<html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>Server got itself in trouble</body></html>
```

Am I wrong in thinking that "'"$(date +%A)"'" should work in this situation?  Also I'd like to add how many days until the weekend, probably something like:

```
6 - $(date +%u)
```

I appreciate that I could do this very easily by doing some calculations before curl and referencing those but would like to do it in a single line if possible.  The line is referenced from an .sh file at present, not a single line in cron.

This is the full line as requested:

```
curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: apiPass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"entity_id": "media_player.Living_room_Home", "message": "Its "'"$(date +%A)"'" morning and 2 days until the weekend.  Time to get ready."}' http://ipAddr:8123/api/services/tts/google_say?api_password=apiPass
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `"Its $(date +%A) morning..."`? Good luck.

Comment: That string doesn't look right, I don't think it would work, but I think you haven't shared enough context to understand why the error happens. It would make more sense this way: `"Its $(date +%A) morning and x days until the weekend.  Time to get ready."` but again, I don't think it will, because of a cause not visible from what you posted.

Comment: maybe because `%` is a special character in cron which must be escaped see `man -s5 crontab` `/%`

Comment: If I use `$(date +%A)` it is just taken literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly fine with this line:

```
curl --trace-ascii 1  -X POST -H "x-ha-access: apiPass" -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{"entity_id": "media_player.Living_room_Home", "message": "Its '$(date +%A)' morning and 2 days until the weekend.  Time to get ready."}'
```

With result:

```
== Info:   Trying ::1...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 197 bytes (0xc5)
0000: POST /api/services/tts/google_say?api_password=apiPass HTTP/1.1
0041: Host: localhost
0052: User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
006b: Accept: */*
0078: x-ha-access: apiPass
008e: Content-Type: application/json
00ae: Content-Length: 130
00c3:
=> Send data, 130 bytes (0x82)
0000: {"entity_id": "media_player.Living_room_Home", "message": "Its T
0040: uesday morning and 2 days until the weekend.  Time to get ready.
0080: "}
== Info: upload completely sent off: 130 out of 130 bytes
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2017 21:12:21 GMT
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Content-Length: 0
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000:
== Info: Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
== Info: Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
echo $(( $(date -d 'next saturday' +%j) - $(date +%j) - 1 )) days until the weekend
```

The -d option in GNU date lets you provide a surprisingly flexible description of the date you want.

Comment: I'll have a play with the -d option as looks like it may also be of use too.  Thanks.